# Bin a large matrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a large dataset and I'm trying to plot its scatterplot as well as an overlayed set of binned "summary" data points (in a different color of course). My intended effect is similar to [*this one*](https://michaelstepner.com/binscatter/binscatter-StataConference2014.pdf)

So far, I know how to sort my data's x-y matrix by the x-variable. How can I make it so that I cut this huge matrix into bins of equal width in the x-direction, and then find the average for all the y values within each bin? I feel like this task will be trivial once I can automatically slice my dataset into bins of arbitrary width in the x-direction.

Comment: Is this question related to *Mathematica* ?

Comment: `Histogram` and `HistogramList`

Comment: How will Histogram work if my goal is to bin it as a scatterplot?

Comment: This is Mathematica related because I want to understand matrix manipulation. So far, I have a list of ordered pairs that looks something like: {{1,2} , {3,4}, {5,6} .......  } (with different values of course). I want to cut this list into bins of any given length, and then average the y-values within each bin.

Comment: You might want to look at `BinLists`.

Comment: Alright, that seems similar to what I'm looking for. Now, it's been a while since I've used Mathematica. When I try to use BinLists on my list, it gives me an error because BinLists is only for 1-dimension. Is there a way I can BinLists on the x-values of each ordered pair?

Comment: `BinLists` will work for 2D data see the `Applications` tab on the help page.

Answer (score 1):

Let's generate some random data to play with:

```
data = Table[{x, 0.18 x + 1 + RandomReal[RandomReal[40]]}, {x, 0, 25, 0.01}];
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let us then define a helper function that will calculate the bin-scatter data, given the data and how many bins we want:

```
Clear[binscatter]
binscatter[list_?ListQ, numbins_Integer] := Module[
  {sorted, partitioned},
  sorted = SortBy[First][list];
  partitioned = Partition[sorted, Floor[Length[sorted]/numbins]];
  Mean /@ partitioned
  ]
```

We can try this out on the `data` generated above, by generating e.g. 10 bins:

```
binscatter[data, 10]

(* Out:
{{1.245, 10.869}, {3.745, 11.9407}, {6.245, 11.3557}, {8.745, 12.4129}, {11.245, 12.8107},
  {13.745, 14.8622}, {16.245, 14.0835}, {18.745, 15.305}, {21.245, 13.7489}, 
  {23.745, 15.7441}}    
*)
```

We can then plot the bin-scatter data, e.g. on top of the original data, for comparison:

```
ListPlot[
  {data, binscatter[data, 10]}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Black, Directive[Red, PointSize[0.02]],}
]
```

[image: bin-scatter plot with original data as well]

Comment: What is the name of that distribution?